# GeoFire giving problems with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, geofire

I'm trying to add Geofire to my iOS project that uses Google Firebase as a backend. When I add the Geofire pod and run `pod update` I get this message in terminal...

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase` required by `Podfile`
- `Firebase (~> 2.1)` required by `GeoFire (1.1.0)`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase, Firebase (~> 2.1)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Here is what my Podfile looks like...

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'HopUp' do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'FirebaseAuth'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'GeoFire', '>= 1.1'
end
```

**Any thoughts as to why this is happening?**

All input is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried it with un-commenting your platform line?

Comment: @MikeD I have, it gives me the same error. I appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

One of the solutions was to add the git source to your pod file like so:

```
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
```

Also, check out [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/48) if you have any more problems. This is how I got GeoFire to work with my project.

Answer (score 1):

After they updated Firebase Geofire stopped working, new version of Geofire is coming soon but not known exactly when.

You can try installing an earlier version of Firebase but sooner or later youll have to rewrite quite a bit of code after updating to a new one.